# PostgreSQL: Grouping and Aggregating on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Problem Statement:

I am working on this simple dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/patrickb1912/ipl-complete-dataset-20082020). I have provided a snippet of data with only required columns in below table. Dataset is quite simple, it has all IPL (cricket) matches listed with teams who played each match (team1 and team2) along with winner of that match.

Now I am trying to get total matches played by all teams along with matches won by each team, I have again provided a snippet of output below the code. Same can be performed by "finding all occurrences of a particular team in column team1" + "finding all occurrences of a particular team in column team2".

While the code does give proper result, I can sense this is not the best approach. I would like to know some better way to do it along with good practices and naming conventions to follow.

### Dataset:

| team1 | team2 | winner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Royal Challengers Bangalore | Kolkata Knight Riders | Kolkata Knight Riders |
| Kings XI Punjab | Chennai Super Kings | Chennai Super Kings |
| Delhi Daredevils | Rajasthan Royals | Delhi Daredevils |
| Mumbai Indians | Royal Challengers Bangalore | Royal Challengers Bangalore |
| Kolkata Knight Riders | Deccan Chargers | Kolkata Knight Riders |
| Rajasthan Royals | Kings XI Punjab | Rajasthan Royals |

### Code:

```sql
SELECT t1.team1 AS team, c_t1 + c_t2 AS played, c_w AS won, CAST(c_w AS FLOAT) / (c_t1 + c_t2) * 100 AS won_percentage
FROM 
    (SELECT team1, count(team1) AS c_t1 FROM ipl_m GROUP BY team1) AS t1 
JOIN 
    (SELECT team2, count(team2) AS c_t2 FROM ipl_m GROUP BY team2) AS t2 
ON t1.team1 = t2.team2
JOIN
    (SELECT winner, count(winner) AS c_w FROM ipl_m GROUP BY winner) AS w
ON t1.team1 = w.winner OR t2.team2 = w.winner
ORDER BY won_percentage DESC;
```

### Resulting Table:

| team | played | won | won_percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chennai Super Kings | 178 | 106 | 59.55056179775281 |
| Mumbai Indians | 203 | 120 | 59.11330049261084 |
| Delhi Capitals | 33 | 19 | 57.57575757575758 |
| Sunrisers Hyderabad | 124 | 66 | 53.2258064516129 |
| Kolkata Knight Riders | 192 | 99 | 51.5625 |

### Table Definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ipl_m (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    match_id integer NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    player_of_match VARCHAR(50),
    venue VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    neutral_venue BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    team1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    team2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    toss_winner VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    toss_decision VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    winner VARCHAR(50),
    result VARCHAR(10),
    result_margin float,
    eliminator CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    method VARCHAR(3),
    umpire1 VARCHAR(50),
    umpire2 VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row in `ipl_m` table has one *winner* and one *loser*.
So first extract *winners* and set field `result` (it will be used in counting) to `1`:

```
SELECT 
  winner AS team,
  1 as result
FROM ipl_m
```

Next extract *losers* and set field `result` to `0`:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN team1 = winner THEN team2
    ELSE team1
  AS team,
  0 as result
FROM ipl_m
```

Combine two sets with `UNION`. Now `SELECT` from resulting set grouping by `team` column.

```
SELECT t.team AS team
, COUNT(*) AS played
, SUM(t.result) AS won
FROM (
SELECT 
  winner AS team,
  1 as result
FROM ipl_m
UNION
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN team1 = winner THEN team2
    ELSE team1
  AS team,
  0 as result
FROM ipl_m
) AS t
GROUP BY t.team
```

Your solution uses 4 `SELECT` and 2 `JOIN` operators. Mine uses 3 `SELECT` and 1 `UNION`. Using fewer operations is usually preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Initially your code didn't work as is, just needed to add an END to that CASE statement. Also UNION removes duplicates, so UNION ALL should be used instead. After making those changes, things work perfectly!

Comment: CASE ... END - my bad. UNION ALL - you are right !